# Dart/Flutter: azureblob headers - The metadata specified is invalid. It has characters that are not permitted

Tags: flutter, azure, dart, azure-blob-storage

in my dart/flutter project I want to upload some blob-data to azure. I am using the package [azblob](https://pub.dev/packages/azblob). There I am allowed to add headers to the request and I want to give the headers request the `"x-ms-range"` to set tags.

I have following demo the upload to azure - it works, when I do not set the header argument:

```
Map<String, String> headers = { "x-ms-range": "VIN=TEST1" };
await storage.putBlob('/$container/$key.txt', body: 'Halllooo',headers: headers);
```

From the azure server, I get following exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidMetadata</Code><Message>The metadata specified is invalid. It has characters that are not permitted.
```

Did I need extra formatting of the header? - or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a SQL-Table to store these metadatas, I was not able to figure out what was the problem. - Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying that the metadata you are trying to set is invalid. The "x-ms-range" header is used to specify a range of bytes to upload, not to set tags. To set tags on a blob, you should use the "x-ms-meta-" prefix followed by the key of the tag. For example, to set a tag with the key "VIN" and the value "TEST1", you should use the header "x-ms-meta-VIN: TEST1"

Comment: Thank you, but now I get following error: `Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.` [...] `The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'XXX...' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign`